# playing video playlist of m3u8

Tags: android-video-player

I am trying to play video of **format m3u8**. I am done with my code but on running the application only a black screen is shown as output.
I imported vitamio player but along with that, error shows up in logcat as:

```
   11-30 16:23:48.905: ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(348):     at  io.vov.vitamio.VitamioInstaller.checkVitamioInstallation(SourceFile:247).
```

Please provide me a code to play the video.

Answer (score 0):

Install the vitamio plugin from market and try to play. If you have installed already then it seems like there is problem in your coding. After setting the datasource to player say videoView.requestFocus(). It may help :)